# Caching with Cedar/Memcache/Rails 3.1

Tags: heroku, memcached, ruby-on-rails-3.1, cedar

So I have been trying to get caching to work on my private website, which basically just serves static stuff with little dynamic stuff in it. Since I am going to deply to Heroku Cedar, I have to go with Memcache instead of Varnish. However, I do not seem to be able to make it cache.

I always get cache: stale, invalid, store.

The way I cache is to set the appropriate config params, and use the built-in cache_pages method of ActionController. Can someone help me debugging this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i decided to use Cloudflare for caching, after a couple days of running, i received significant boost in performance/caching.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same. But it looks like page caching works.